# Is there a way to hold back water sources without using a bunch of ugly signs or fence gates?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

[image]

using signs and fence gates is ugly, is there any other way to do it?

Comment: Can't you remove 1 layer of blocks at the bottom? this would prevent the water from floating sideways, because it only does so when hitting the bottom.

Comment: Have you tried [glass](https://minecraft.fandom.com/wiki/Glass)?

Comment: @Mixxiphoid was about to suggest this b far easiest of all solutions. And even if not: OP, you can remove all but the lowest signposts already without any problem

Comment: I like iron bars, they look better than signs and allow you to diagonally enter at the sides.

Comment: OP cannot remove 1 layer of blocks at the bottom or keep 1 layer of signposts since the bubble columns are source blocks. Unlike flowing water, source blocks will spread out to its 4 sides if it can.

Comment: Assuming you're in creative, you can use structure void blocks to prevent liquids from flowing into them. This has the benefit of not having block updates cause your contraption to break (unlike the block update suppression method) but it does leave a tiny cube (smaller than a normal block) hitbox that you may or may not notice

Comment: @Hobbamok all the water is source blocks so they will flow out if there are any updates. I ended up using chains, they weren't the prettiest and are harder to pass through but it was the best I could do with my space

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There are three ways - differing in difficulty and robustness. Unfortunately for your case (3x3 surface) only the last, which is really hard, would suffice - but if you're willing to "scale back" a bit, you can achieve decent effects on smaller budget.

First, the easiest - water source block finds the "nearest hole" when placed, and flows towards it (or splits if there are more within same distance). It scans the area up to 5 blocks away, but only when updated - placed, or something is placed or removed adjacent to it. It doesn't check for other terrain changes. So if you trigger such directional flow, you can remove blocks around that provided "path of greater resistance" and have water "hanging over the edge:

[image]

[image]

The second one is based upon a glitch, where a retracting piston head that fails to pull a slime block structure doesn't update adjacent water. In the below example, the process is in two steps, first four pistons fail to move the structure blocked by obsidian blocks, then after removing them, I can add a second structure, then retract the last piston head:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

This technique allows for quite fancy 'floating water' features, and quite a bit of flexibility, but the necessity for the piston on one side, the slime block structure on the other, and the fact removing them updates the water, limits applications in case of wider streams.

Then we come to expert techniques. They are way too complex to describe in a simple Q&A answer - there's [block update suppression](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/387746/9440), which can be used to remove temporary blocks holding water in place, without updating the water, [chunk savestating](https://mcdiscontinued.miraheze.org/wiki/Chunk_Savestating) which can be used to erase any changes within a chunk (including water flowing into it from water sources) without updating blocks in neighboring chunks, and modded features like Carpet Mod's fillUpdates rule, after which you can perform a /fill command that won't update adjacent blocks (and e.g. erase flowing water).

In your case, though, I believe the most viable approach is to accept that water will flow to the sides - and 'sink' it in waterlogged blocks:

[image]
[image]

Comment: I believe water looks up to 8 blocks for a hole

Comment: @user253751 Neither. [The correct number is 5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s66BU.png). 4 if not counting the block directly underneath the source.

Answer (score 5):

You can use half slabs, which are more easily integrated with the surrounding environment. Trap doors can also serve the same purpose

Comment: doors work as well

Answer (score 0):

There are three ways in which "partial" blocks can interact with water.  Water either:

1. Flows in and wipes them out
2. Flows in and "waterlogs" the space (coexists with it) or
3. Is blocked by it.

Signs and fence gates are part of this third category...which is why they work. You're looking for other objects that fit into this third category.

Given the application you're picturing...I would try Chains. I know they're not a category 1 item, and I don't think they're category 2 either. They don't merge together to block passage like glass or iron bars would. If you're not familiar, a Chain is made from an iron nugget, iron ingot, iron nugget in the middle column of the craft table.

Another potential option is Lightning Rods. Copper ingot, copper ingot, copper ingot in the middle column of the craft table.

Give those two a go and see if they'll suit your purpose.